# cant get react routing to work, dosent who the comopnents

Tags: reactjs, routes

Why is my routing in react not working. i have done it before but for some reson im missing something i think? compared it to my other projcets but cant find the issue. i have installed the routing package (react-route-dom). i cant see any componets, non

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Layout />} >
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
          <Route path='/contact' element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path='/booking' element={<Booking />} />
          <Route path='/admin' element={<Admin />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

export function Layout(){
    return(<>
     <Header/>
        <main>
            <Outlet></Outlet>
        </main>
    
    </>)
}
```

Comment: which version of react-router-dom is being used here?

Comment: it says ^6.3.0.

Comment: someone have any anwser? it work if i dont have the Layout element end index. why i dont know. copied the one that worked but still dosent work. checked every corner why :S